# English equivalent of "a**holes don't have horns"

Tags: phrase-requests, translation, pejorative-language

We have this expression in Hindi slang. Situation:

> A: "I can't believe he treated me like that. I was stupid to trust him"
>
> B: "Don't beat yourself up. How were you supposed to know he would stoop so low? After all, a**holes don't walk around with horns on their
>   heads"

What B is trying to say is that bad people don't have distinctive physical characteristics. They look like normal people and there's no way to tell them apart.

Is there some English expression that conveys this?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use that phrase exactly as you've written it? I've definitely heard variations on it before ("don't walk around"), so it sounds very natural to me.

Comment: Namaste, funnily enough I'm pretty sure **I have heard that type of phrase** in English -- so, "the devil doesn't always have horns!"  It would be absolutely understandable in English.

Comment: Note that Centaurus has solved it below .. good one

Comment: [*Devil in plain sight*](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DevilInPlainSight) ?

Comment: Omg! the phrase was brought in some three centuries ago!

Comment: A related expression that comes to mind is "Fool me once: shame on you, Fool me twice: shame on me"

Comment: *'Asses don't have horns' should be the correct translation. The word used in Hindi is for the animal ass and not for the anal opening.

Comment: @CodeNewbie: I know. I was trying to translate the connotation, not the word. Translating word-for-word is never a good idea.

Comment: I was trying to picture a hole with horns and it was getting pretty bizarre. I think I'll never understand this bowlderizing asterisk mania…

Comment: @Lohoris: If it was you who downvoted, I politely call to you attention the fact that you wouldn't have to imagine anything if you had bothered to read my post. Assholes(bad people) don't walk around with horns on their heads. **Their heads**. Heads are a pretty common place to expect horns on.

Comment: Leonard Cohen wrote a poem describing Adolf Eichmann's physical characteristics, which unsurprisingly were normal.  The poem ends something like: "What did you expect? Talons? ... Green saliva?"

Comment: RE: _you wouldn't have to imagine anything if you had bothered to read my post_ I don't see how that qualfies as a "polite" clarification.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**I suggest this old saying by Tucker Max**  "How were you supposed to know he would stoop so low? After all, the devil.......

[image: I suggest this old saying by Tucker Max.]

Tucker Max -  [an American author and public speaker.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tucker_Max)

Comment: +1 but beware: it's very clear what this quote is saying and it very closely matches  the meaning requested by the OP, therefore it's a good answer; but it's not a well-known "expression".

Answer (score 9):

Area, the only phrase I can think of that's like this is, you sometimes hear variations on "sign on their head" or "sign hanging over their head" or "sign over their head..."

So, "assholes don't go around with signs over their head" or "I wish idiots had a sign over their head alerting me to the fact they were idiots.." sort of thing.

As I mention in a comment, it's absolutely understandable.  And, I'm pretty sure I've actually heard someone say something pretty much like this (using the word "horns") in English.  So, you know, something like "the devil doesn't go around with horns and a tail!"

{Footnote: My grandparents etc are Scottish and I get some subtle linguistic clues from them. it's just possible there is some connection there since, as you know, there are many connections to Scottish usage, accent, etc in the subcontinent. perhaps there's a scottish saying along the lines of devils not always coming with handy visible horns (that would be typically miserable of scots grandmothers!)}

Comment: I like the sign over the head, I have heard that said.

Comment: I like this one too. Upvote. Please provide some sources, though.

Comment: i don't honestly have an refs for that .. sorry!

Comment: Sign could also be substituted for "Warning Label" with the same effect.

Comment: Sounds a lot like Bill Engvall's famous "Here's your sign" standup routine: "I just hate stupid people.  They should have to wear signs that say 'I'm Stupid'.  That way you wouldn't rely on them.  You wouldn't ask them anything. You'd be like, 'Excuse me... oh, sorry, nevermind. I didn't see your sign.'"

Comment: It's used in all sorts of situations: [*A neon sign flashing "Drug Dealer" above his head...*](https://books.google.it/books?id=Cju_BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT40&dq=%22neon+sign%22+flashing++head&hl=en&sa=X&ei=589DVbWDAYOAU_vlgJAJ&ved=0CFYQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22neon%20sign%22%20flashing%20%20head&f=false)

Comment: [*He might as well as had a neon sign flashing ‘Liar’ over his head.*](https://books.google.it/books?id=oTTaO4C_J3MC&pg=PT96&dq=%22neon+sign%22+flashing++head&hl=en&sa=X&ei=589DVbWDAYOAU_vlgJAJ&ved=0CEUQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22neon%20sign%22%20flashing%20%20head&f=false)

Comment: Also variants of "it doesn't say it on their t-shirt..."

Answer (score 4):

Shakespeare said that someone (Iago, I think) "could smile and smile and be a villain", also that "There's no art to find the mind's construction in the face." (Macbeth) Can you use that?

The Hindi expression is a good one, we should steal it.

Comment: Imagine using Shakespeare to console a friend who's been dumped. Now I'm the a-hole!

Answer (score 3):

A phrase that came to mind was *Evil doesn't advertise* but apparently it isn't widely used, nor is *The Devil doesn't advertise*, so I don't know if I'm misremembering something there.

While we're on Shakespeare however, from *Hamlet*,

> the devil hath power to assume a pleasing shape

Comment: outstanding. yes, of course "Evil doesn't advertise" or "The Devil doesn't advertise" is something of a phrase. (For example, consider the 30s novel "Murder must advertise" .. a play on those.)

Answer (score 1):

Why not Shakespeare? In *Othello* Iago says:

> [But I will wear my heart upon my sleeve](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/403000.html)

that is, he claims to display his emotions openly, but of course he does quite the opposite. If you explicitly want a slang expression (something modern), Shakespeare actually made it to the [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wearing%20your%20heart%20on%20your%20sleeve). Since the Hindi expression also uses a negative construction you could say something along the lines of: *people don't wear their hearts on their sleeve*. Or, if your English speaking friend is familiar with Shakespeare's work, you could just call the treacherous, [stony-hearted](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/334800.html) [devil incarnate](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/356950.html) - Iago.

P.S. If you want to offer words of comfort, after a while saying that this person's leaving was [good riddance](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/good-riddance.html) might be the right phrase.

Answer (score 0):

"[A wolf in sheep's clothing](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/britannico/a-wolf-in-sheep-s-clothing)" comes to mind:

> - a person who hides the fact that they are evil, with a pleasant and friendly appearance. (Cambridge Dictionary)

- After all, how could you say  that he was a wolf in sheep's clothing?

Comment: Good one. I'm sorry if this seems a bit anal, but there's a slight difference. A wolf in sheep's clothing implies the wolf is actively trying to hide his appearance to fit in. I'm looking for something that means bad people look the same without trying.

Comment: You're not being anal.  It's really totally unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker of American English, the best equivalent I can think of is people "wearing a sign" to indicate what their qualities are. Not really used as an idiom but definitely a common metaphor. [Here's Your Sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here%27s_Your_Sign) is a comedy album by Bill Engvall named after this concept.